# Why is this texture not showing when using explosion modifier?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, particles

I'm new to Blender and trying to learn how to dissolve a textured plane. Using this [tutorial](http://www.cleveron.com/blender/dissolve/basics/), I've managed to get most of the way. I'm stuck on getting the particles to fade though.

The main difference between what I'm trying to do & the tutorial seems to be that a solid colour on a material is used in the tutorial, whereas I'm trying to work with a texture.

Have worked through the tutorial a few times. The problem seems to occur when in the explosion modifier, I add the plane's UV data under the particle UV heading. This causes the texture to disappear. 
[image]

The plane with the texture isn't visible until midway through the explosion effect, and after that is only intermittantly visible (in texture & material view). Rendering is the same.

Can anyone give me a nudge in the right direction? Thanks for reading!

Comment: Do you have one large plane, and one small plane? Are they on the same euclidean plane by any chance? What happens if you move the smaller plane up the Z axis a little bit?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The smaller, textured plane is +0.2 on the Z. Tried increasing this up as far as 2, but it still disappears when the particle UV is set.